# Pegando o dado do campo value dinamicamente em Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou com dificuldade em implementar um botão deslogar em jquery...
gero uma lista de usuário que estão logados em tela de admin o admin pode deslogar o usuario
O Problema e que o botão só mostra o primeiro usuário da lista

```
 $('.comment-phara').on('click','#deslogar', function () {
    var select = $('#deslogar').val();
    alert(select);
    Lobibox.notify('info', {
        msg: 'Usuario deslogado já pode logar na estação.'
    });
});
                             <?php 
                                foreach ($logados as $usuarios){
                                    echo '<li class="lista">'
                                    . '<div class="comment-phara">'
                                            . '<div class="comment-adminpr">'
                                            . '<p class="dashtwo-messsage-title"  id="id_usuario"/>' . $usuarios['nome_completo'] . '</p>'
                                            . '</div>'
                                            . '<div class="admin-comment-month">'
                                            . '<p class="comment-clock"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Logou as 16:55</p>'
                                            . '<br>'
                                            . '<button class="btn btn-custon-four btn-primary btn-xs" id="deslogar" value="'. $usuarios['nome_completo'] .'">Deslogar</button>'
                                            . '</div>'
                                            . '</div>'
                                            . '</li>';
                                    
                                }
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha dois principais problemas na lógica, o primeiro está em criar um elemento com um id que será repetido em tela, idealmente ids devem ser únicos no DOM. Se você criar elementos em uma estrutura de repetição como `foreach` e precisar adicionar um id a algum deles, tente incluir uma chave que pertença ao objeto percorrido, em outros casos de preferência a utilização de classes.

O segundo problema esta na forma como você pega o valor do item que foi clicado, ao usar o comando `$('#deslogar').val()` ainda que ele procurasse por uma classe, você está pegando qualquer elemento da tela que corresponda ao valor de busca, ao invés de usar um termo para buscar pelo elemento, você pode usar o objeto `this` desta forma:

```
$(this).val();
```

`this` é o objeto que corresponde ao elemento que teve o evento disparado.

Comment: Perfeito bombou com o  $(this).val(); Como uso o mesmo botão me salvou cara!! Vou usar a classe também.